# I can't enter the system

Tags: grub2, system

When I meet some errors,I shut down my computer. 
When I reboot it displays .

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda10: recovering journal
/dev/sda10: clean,282317/4087808 files,6470239/16339200 block
```

for a long time.
how can I solve it?
ps:sda10 is the part where ubuntu at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fsck` is the disk checking utility for Ubuntu (and other Linux) systems.

The partition `/dev/sda10` is being checked for errors.

You will normally just have to wait for this disk check to finish.

If this is happening every time you boot the system, it's probably related to whatever errors you're having before you shutdown. The OS is not happy that the system has shut down in a clean way, and is checking the partition for corruption before restarting.

Solving the errors which cause you to shutdown is the first step towards resolving this. It may be worth starting a new question with details of the errors which cause you to shutdown, including the steps you take to shut down (e.g. using GUI, pressing power button etc.)

Comment: got it.The only thing i should do is waiting:)Thank you

Comment: @jinxinking If the answer helped, could you click the grey tick to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted please? Glad to help :)